# How to write correct htaccess rule?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, laravel

I have a URL that looks like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=item&id=92954
```

And now I need it to redirect to

```
http://example.com/item/show/92954
```

instead of 92954 there can be any other number which is the ID of an item. How can I create such an htaccess rule?

I am using Laravel as a backend.

Comment: but laravel is providing it within it, read about resources in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers

Comment: @YehiaAwad damn man, I am an idiot. Please post your comment as an answer - I will mark it as a solution. I absolutely forgot that such a URL will route to main controller and I can parse request params.

Comment: it is fine it happens to all of us, you must be new to the framework )

Comment: @YehiaAwad no, I have been using it for long. Just got out of the mind, that I don't have to use htaccess. I am migrating my site from CMS to laravel and have to keep a lot in my head, and suddenly keep forgeting simple things. I am writing this redirect, so that google searches would lead to the correct destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides it within it:

> Resource controllers make it painless to build `RESTful` controllers
>   around resources. For example, you may wish to create a controller
>   that handles HTTP requests regarding "photos" stored by your
>   application. Using the make:controller Artisan command, we can quickly
>   create such a controller

read more about resources in Laravel [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers)